# Redirect when target page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am trying to implement a affiliate link on my website. I used to do it with JavaScript, but I would like to keep the link in the controller and not hand it over to JavaScript or html in the future. With JavaScript I waited until the target page was loaded (or at least 1 sec) and redirected the user to that page afterwards.

If I use "redirect_to" in my rails controller it redirects directly, which hides the view completely. Is there any way to use redirect_to after a certain amount of time so at least my view shows up or after the target page has fully loaded?

Code example below:

```
def index
   redirect_to www.google.com
end
```

Comment: set the redirect url to a variable in controller and use `$(window).load()...`.with `window.location`

Comment: That is exactly what I currently do. But the url would then be visible in the JS code, which is not my intension.

Comment: But Chris, once the redirect occurs the link will be visible to the user anyways.  What is your intention, to try to hide the link from your user's or to manage the link in Ruby?

Comment: Hide the link from search engines is the main intention for me. Your post below should therefore solve the problem as the link is inside the controller and not inside my js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Ruby Sleep method, just know that it is wasting resources and would not achieve your desired effect.

```
def index
   sleep 3
   redirect_to www.google.com
end
```

A JS solution would be a higher performing solution.  If you are worried about users viewing the link than I would suggest this approach.  Use JS to detect when the page loads, and have it wait for whatever amount of time your users need to view before redirection.  Then use JS to redirect to a different controller action on your site that will have the direct redirect.  This will ensure the page loads for the user before redirect, the user has enough time to view what is on that page, and your affiliate link is in Ruby not JS such as:

```
def redirect_to_affiliate
   redirect_to www.google.com
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So the action is triggered when a user clicks the affiliate link?

There are other ways, but i don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
def affiliate_link
  sleep 2 # or whatever you deem appropriate

  # some other code
  redirect_to some_path
end
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. The user clicks a link, a page opens where the redirect happens. Therefore I can't use sleep as the view of the redirect page wouldn't render.

Comment: sorry, guess I don't understand what you mean then - in your post you say:  "If I use "redirect_to" in my rails controller it redirects directly, which hides the view completely. Is there any way to use redirect_to after a certain amount of time so at least my view shows up or after the target page has fully loaded?"  Can you explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: 1. the user clicks on a page on a link (detailpage controller) -> gets redirected to the out-page

2. the user lands on the out page (out-controller) and needs be redirected to the target page automatically 

The code I posted is from the out-controller. This controller should redirect the user to the target page automatically. If I add sleep 2 to the index method, the complete view is blocked for 2 seconds, which means, the view is not rendering and the user will see a empty page. My intention is the show the user a loading page instead.